# Add Auth::user() to Eloquent save (); request

Tags: laravel-5.3

How can I write the two lines of code below into one line of code:

```
$service_review->user_id=\Auth::user(); 

$user_service->service_reviews()->save($service_review);
```

The reason being that the line including Auth::user() is throwing an error since it's a foreign key in my "service_reviews" table and so "DOESN'T HAVE A DEFAULT VALUE"

The problem is if I give precedence to:

```
\Auth::user()->service_reviews()->save($service_review);
```

Then in this case, the authorized user is fetched but my user_service_id now throws the error as "DOESN'T HAVE A DEFAULT VALUE".

The code of my store method (This is from my ReviewsController that is based on a Nested Route:

Route::resource("services.reviews", "ReviewsController"); is as follows:

```
public function store(ReviewsRequest $request, $id){

    $service_review = new Service_review($request->all());

    $user_service = User_service::findOrFail($id);

    $service_review->user_id=\Auth::user(); 

    $user_service->service_reviews()->save($service_review);

    return redirect("reviews");
```

I reckon passing them in one line of code will solve this error.

Comment: I am not sure what's wrong exactly, but I noticed you should use `Auth::user()->id` in order to get the exact `id`, not a complete object.

Answer (score 0):

Yes your're right @MinaAbadir

I ended up doing it as follows:

```
public function store(ReviewsRequest $request, $id){

    $service_review = new Service_review($request->all());

    $user_service = User_service::findOrFail($id);

    $service_review->user_id = \Auth::user()->email;

    $user_service->service_reviews()->save($service_review);

    return redirect("reviews");

}
```

It seems calling the specific column you want retrieved negates the foreign key problem. Maybe MySQL figures out the relationship via Eloquent. Let me know if I can clean this up further.